# A basic issue involving too much space after an exclamation mark followed by a closing parenthesis

Tags: spacing

Kindly consider this:

```
here is some (great!) text.
```

For some reasons, I am experiencing a much greater space between `!)` and `text` than between `some` and `(`. The latter space is normal. The former space is abnormally large; it looks like a space that appears after a sentence (i.e. after a dot).

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: You can suppress the extra space using `\@` after the exclamation  mark.

Comment: another way to suppress the extra space is to insert a "slash-space" after the closing paren: `(great!)\ text.`  to my mind (as an unregenerate plain tex devotee) this is preferable to `\@` as it is what is proposed in the texbook.  `\@` also has the meaning of "this *is* the end of a sentence" when it follows an uppercase letter, and i don't like the ambiguity.

Comment: I always thought `(great!)\ text` was the preferred way to do it in LaTeX, too. At the top of page 15 of Lamport's LaTeX 2e manual, he has `Beans (lima, etc.)\ have ...` as an example of how to deal with this situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your observation is correct:

```
\documentclass{article}
\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
\tracingonline=1
\begin{document}
\sbox0{Here is some (great!) text. Another word.}
\usebox0
\scrollmode
\showbox0
\end{document}
```

> [image: Space is too large]

The box contents:

```
> \box0=
\hbox(7.5+2.5)x184.1114
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 H
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 r
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
.\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 i
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 s
.\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 s
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 o
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 m
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
.\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 g
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 r
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 a
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 t
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 !
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 )
.\glue 4.44444 plus 4.99997 minus 0.37036
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 t
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 x
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 t
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 .
.\glue 4.44444 plus 4.99997 minus 0.37036
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 A
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 n
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 o
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 t
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 h
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 r
.\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 w
.\kern-0.27779
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 o
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 r
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 d
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 .

! OK.
l.13 \showbox0
```

The space after the closing parenthesis is indeed the same as the space after the period.
This is controlled by the space factor. This is explained in more detail in **Chapter 20: Spacing** of Eijkhout's [**TeX by Topic**](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf).

The space factor can be print on the screen/`.log` file:

```
\typeout{sfcode[t]: \the\sfcode`t}
\typeout{sfcode[!]: \the\sfcode`!}
\typeout{sfcode[)]: \the\sfcode`\)}
```

The space factors are:

```
sfcode[t]: 1000
sfcode[!]: 3000
sfcode[)]: 0
```

After `great` the space factor is `1000`. The following `!` increases it to `3000`. The closing `)`, however, does not change the space factor, because its `\sfcode` is zero.
Therefore the large space is used afterwards.

It can be fixed by `\@`. It is a macro that sets the space factor to `1000`:

```
Here is some (great!)\@ text. Another word.
```

> [image: Fixed spacing]

And `\showbox` confirms:

```
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 !
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 )
.\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 t
```

An alternative would be to change the space factor of `)`, e.g.:

```
\sfcode`\)=1000
```

But this will not solve the problem, the parentheses could contain a whole sentence.
Then the larger space would be needed:

```
(This is a sentence!) Another sentence follows.
```